# When is android PagerAdapter's instantiateItem called?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a viewpager and a pagerAdapter which inflates a custom view and adds it to the collection. After setting up the viewpager and pageradapter, I proceed to get some data which I now want to display in one of the custom views. However I observed that the pagerAdapter.instantiateItem is not being called by that time. How can I get the viewpager to start instantiateItem right away?

Comment: `instantiateItem` of PagerAdapter is called every time fragment is accessed or created from ViewPager. If fragment is not created at this moment, `getItem` will get called.

Answer (score 2):

`instantiateItem` is called when the `viewPager` calls the `getItem` method. When the `viewPager` is first displayed, `getItem` is called for the currently displayed tab and the following tab.

Could you provide a code snippet for further details ?